# Text colour variable to background colour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got sections of the site with dark coloured imagery and then other panels of white. In a fixed position in the top left hand corner are some simple navigation dots that the user can click on to move through the site. However, of course these dots become invisible when scrolling over white backgrounds.

Link to the dev site is here: http://dev.matthewbugeja.com/

My question is: is it possible to have those dotes change to black when on white areas of the site and then revert back to white when on darker areas? Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: Yes it is possible. please share the relevant code.

Comment: I am not gonna visit dev site

Comment: http://cube3x.com/backgroundcheck-change-text-color-based-on-background/

Comment: The simple solution would be adding the dark border around the white dots.
In dark background, that dark border will be invisible.
In light background, dots will be visible because of dark border around them.

Answer (score 0):

you can make color changes to the dots by checking the window scroll value for eg check below code

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 500) {

        $("#nav ul li a").css("color", "#000000");

    } 
})
```

Note that value 500 is an example here you may have different scroll value checks.

Comment: Incase you do not want to use scripting, you can alter the visual appearence of the dots by adding the following css code 
    #nav ul li a{
                text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
               -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #d7d7d7;
                }

Comment: The jQuery you listed works great! However it doesn't account for the changing of window size. So I could set the correct value for one window size, but as soon as I decrease or increase it the value will be inaccurate for the position I need it to change on the page. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: I'll just double check with respect to window size, meanwhile have you considered altering the CSS by adding the following :
 #nav ul li a{ text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000; -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #d7d7d7; }